# Oracle - Convert datetime format

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a temp table.

It has last_update column in `2/10/2018 6:01:50 PM` datetime format.

How can I write *THE BEST QUERY* to display all information that's updated on 02-Oct-2018 **day**?

Comment: use function to_date('02-oct-2018','dd-mon-yyyy')

Comment: You shouldn't be storing timestamp values in a `varchar` column to begin with. That is a really bad idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is preferable to avoid `TRUNC` especially if you have an index on the column `last_update`. 
A simple `where` condition should be better and may be better performant.

```
WHERE last_update >= date '2018-10-02' AND
      last_update <  date '2018-10-02' + 1
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `trunc` function

```
select *
  from tab
 where trunc(last_update) = date'2018-10-02'
```

Comment: @user7294900 [Basic Elements of Oracle SQL](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Literals.html#GUID-8F4B3F82-8821-4071-84D6-FBBA21C05AC1)

Answer (score 2):

Use [trunc](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions201.htm) function for getting the same day:

```
trunc(last_update) = trunc(to_date('02-Oct-2018', 'DD-MONTH-YYYY'))
```

> The TRUNC (date) function returns date with the time portion of the day truncated to the unit specified by the format model fmt. The value returned is always of datatype DATE, even if you specify a different datetime datatype for date. **If you omit fmt, then date is truncated to the nearest day**.

You can also use format `DD-MON-YYYY`